# List View Box, Double clicking to a text box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listview

I have a form with a `list view box` that contains two columns of data, and the same form I have two columns of text boxes.

I would like to make it so that if I double click a row of `listview` it will past the value into a line of `textboxes` on the same page.

How to achive this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick

        TextBox1.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
        TextBox2.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text


    End Sub
```